# Windows authentication box pops up with integrated authentication on web page

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, ntlm

I am running two Windows server 2016s with IIS 10.0.14393. One server for staging purposes, and one for production.

The application has one "front-end app" and one "back-end REST api" running on the same IIS server. The front end communicates with the backend (suprise!). The difficulty I am facing is that the staging server works as expected, i.e no "Sign in" box appears when entering the front-end web page (React). However, on the production server this box pops-up.

When the page is loaded, there is javascript that fetches some information from the API, and it seems that this async fetch is causing the pop-up to occur (the request is in pending mode until login).

I have studied the configuration of IIS on the two servers but can't seem to find any obvious differences.

Both instances have both windows authentication and anonymous authentication turned on for both front-end and backe-end. I need this as the API has different types of authentication for the endpoints.

Anyone that has solved a similar issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to set the internet security settings to automatic logon with current username and password? Control Panel > Internet Options > Security tab > choose the correct "zone" > Custom Level > scroll to the bottom [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApA9H.png)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this was already set.

Answer (score 0):

If someone experiences a similar issue the following link may help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

In my case I was sending the request to the api with the full domain url. The problem was fixed by just using the machine name (and port in my case) when sending the request. If the whole domain with punctuation is used, the system believes that the request is meant for the Internet and not the intranet, and will not include any credentials.

Another, and probably more robust solution, is to add the site in question to: Internet properties -> security -> Local intranet -> sites -> advanced.